# Initialise attributes in a class from a list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to initialise the attributes in a class from a list, is there a way to do this without explicitly listing each attribute independently as given in the function `initialise_from_list`.

```
class testClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.second = None

    def initialise_from_list(self, l):
        self.first = l[0]
        self.second = l[1]
        print (self.first, self.second)

t = testClass()
t.initialise_from_list(l=[1,2])
```

Comment: Do you have the attributes listed like `"first", "second"`...? Where do those names come from?

Comment: `self.first, self.second = l`? Or do you want to go further and get rid of first and second?

Comment: I want to get rid of `self.first, self.second` completely. The list has approximately 40 elements, and listing them is a pain

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
attrs = ["first", "second", "third", ...]  # however many you need

def initialise_from_list(self, l):
    for k, v in zip(self.attrs, l):
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

But I would advise against it. The *Zen of Python* (`import this` in your interpreter) states:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

And most IDEs will work much better in terms of code completion and other features if you set attributes explicitly.